# HTML recursive binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a datatble as below:

```
id      menuname    url                  parentid
1       Home        ~/Home.aspx          NULL   
2       Product     ~/products.aspx      NULL 
3       Services    ~/services.aspx      NULL   
4       ERP     ~/erp.aspx           2
5       HRM         ~/hrm.aspx           4
7       Payroll     ~/payroll.aspx       4
8       Programming ~/programming.aspx   3
9       Advertising ~/advert.aspx        3
10      Television Advert ~/tvadvert.aspx 9
11      Radio Advert ~/radioadvert.aspx  9
........
........
```

So i want to generate menu item into an unordered list based on the datatable above such that the items with null parentid should be the first level menu
and others will be submenus based on their parentid like so:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="home.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="produc.aspx">Product</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a href="erp.aspx">ERP</a>  
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="hrm.aspx">HRM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="payroll.aspx">Payroll</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="services.aspx">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="programming.aspx">Advertising</a></li>
                <li><a href="advert.aspx">Programming</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>

    .....etc
</ul>
```

below is my code that seem incomplete:

```
public static String AddToList() 
    {


        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table = GetMenus();

        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows())
        {
            string parentId = row["parentmenuId"].ToString();
            //string url = Server.MapPath(m.Url);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentId))
            {
                sb.Append(String.Format("<ul class=\"menu\"><li><a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a></li></ul>", row["Url"].ToString(), row["Description"].ToString()));
            }

        }

        return sb.ToString();

    }




This gets all top menu but all other effort to get submenu doesnt work. Pls help me out.

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: to start with, there's no recursion in your code.

Comment: I assume that the tree-like structure of the menu implies recursion in the code that renders it.

Comment: thanks for not letting me know if this was helpful or not. is it really that hard to comment/accept/decline an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of pure boredom, usnig the Compositin of controls asp.net (each control has a Controls property), which is already a tree and rendered as such (which means i dont need a real recursion), and an array of indexes for easy by-id access to created controls

```
  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form.Controls.Add(AddToList()); 
    }

   public static HtmlGenericControl AddToList()      
   {
       HtmlGenericControl menu = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
       DataTable table = GetMenus();
       //NOTE  i initialized this to 7, because this is the max rows id, and
       // im basing my builder on indexes to work. This can be easily replaced to
       // a dictionary<int,HtmlGenericControl> or any othre suitable collection
       HtmlGenericControl[] arrayOfLists = new HtmlGenericControl[7];
       foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
       {
          //assume control has no children, unless proved otherwise
           HtmlGenericControl temp  = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
           //add the control to its indexes place in the array and init it
           arrayOfLists[(int)row["id"] - 1] = temp;
           HtmlAnchor link = new HtmlAnchor();
           link.HRef = row["url"].ToString();
           link.InnerText = row["menuname"].ToString();
           temp.Controls.Add(link);
           int? parentId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["parentmenuId"].ToString()) ? null : (int?)int.Parse(row["parentmenuId"].ToString());
           if (parentId.HasValue)
           {
               // if a control has a parent - make its parent a ul insead of li
              // and add it to the parents collection
               arrayOfLists[parentId.Value - 1].TagName = "ul";
               arrayOfLists[parentId.Value - 1].Controls.Add(arrayOfLists[(int)row["id"] - 1]);
           }
           else
           {
                // no parent = add to the first created ul menu
               menu.Controls.Add(temp);
           }

       }

       return menu;     
   }

   public static DataTable GetMenus()
   {
       DataTable dt = new DataTable ();
       dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
       dt.Columns.Add("menuname", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("url", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("parentmenuId", typeof(string));
       dt.Rows.Add(1,"Home","~/Home.aspx",        null  );
       dt.Rows.Add( 2,"Product","~/products.aspx",    null);
       dt.Rows.Add(3,"services", "~/services.aspx",null);
       dt.Rows.Add(4, "ERP",  "~/erp.aspx",           "2" );
       dt.Rows.Add( 5  ,"HRM" ,"~/hrm.aspx",           "4" );
       dt.Rows.Add(7, " Payroll", "~/payroll.aspx", "4");
       return dt;

   }
```